# Programmatically scroll to a supplementary view within UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uicollectionview

I am using `UICollectionView` to display photos in sections. Each section has a supplementary view as a header and is supplied via the method: `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`.

I have a scrubber on the side that allows the user to jump from section to section. For now I am scrolling to the first item in the section using `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`, but what I really want is to scroll the collectionView so that that section's header is at the top of the screen, not the first cell. I do not see an obvious method to do this with. Do any of you have a work around?

I suppose I could scroll to the first item of the section, and then offset that by the supplementary height plus the offset between the items and header if it comes down to that (there is a method for scrolling to point coordinates of the contentView). However if there is a simpler way, I'd like to know.

Thanks.

Comment: what's the problem about it? it should work nice since every supplementary view has its index path

Comment: Yes, they do indeed have indexPaths. I did a print out for both delegate methods that prep the cell and supplementary cell. The indexPaths are not mutually exclusive, rather they look like two distict sets with nonuniue indexPaths. This will probably not paste well here, but: 
!!! Cell index path 0 0
!!! Supp index path 0 0
!!! Cell index path 0 1
!!! Cell index path 0 2
!!! Cell index path 0 3
!!! Cell index path 0 4
!!! Cell index path 0 5
!!! Cell index path 0 6
!!! Cell index path 0 7
!!! Cell index path 0 8
!!! Cell index path 0 9
!!! Cell index path 0 10
!!! Cell index path 0 11

Comment: I should state that I am printing out indexPath.section indexPath.item. Is there another property that I'm overlooking that would set these apart? You can see that [0 0] is in the cell view and supplementary view from what I have printed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You **can not** use `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated` for this.

Hopefully, they will add a new method like `scrollToSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` in the future, but **for now, the only way is to manipulate the contentOffset directly**.

The code below shows how to scroll header to be on top vertically with FlowLayout. You can do the same for horizontal scrolling, or use this idea for other layout types.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = ... // indexPath of your header, item must be 0

CGFloat offsetY = [collectionView layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader atIndexPath:indexPath].frame.origin.y;

CGFloat contentInsetY = self.contentInset.top;
CGFloat sectionInsetY = ((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionView.collectionViewLayout).sectionInset.top;

[collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(collectionView.contentOffset.x, offsetY - contentInsetY - sectionInsetY) animated:YES];
```

Note that if you have non-zero `contentInset` (as in iOS 7, when scroll views expand below bars) you need to subtract it from the `offsetY`, as shown. Same for `sectionInset`.

**Update:**

The code assumes that the layout is in prepared, "valid" state because it uses it to calculate the offset. The layout is prepared when the collection view presents its content.

The call to `[_collectionView.collectionViewLayout prepareLayout]` before the code above may help when you need to scroll the collection view which is not yet presented (from `viewDidLoad` say). The call to `layoutIfNeeded` (as @Vrasidas suggested in comments) should work too because it also prepares the layout.

Comment: This does not work for me.
It crashes at layoutAttributes... with


 `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'layout attributes for supplementary item at index path ([0, 0]) changed from 
             <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x12c8d180> index path: ([0, 0]); element kind: (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader); frame = (0 0; 0 0);   to   <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x12cc99e0> index path: ([0, 0]); element kind: (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader); frame = (0 0; 492 60);  without invalidating the layout'`


Any ideas?

Comment: And I found what was missing...
A call to [collectionView layoutIfNeeded]; before that fixes that problem and it works now!

Comment: One note.  When building the NSIndexPath be sure to set the 'item' to 0.  I just fixed a bug in my use of this where using a non-zero 'item' value caused the UICollectionView to request two supplementary cells when displaying it.  When you scroll that view off screen the collection view only removes one.

Comment: I filed rdar://16572180 asking for this if anyone wants to dupe BTW

Comment: This will potentially scroll past the collectionView.contentSize boundary if your section is shorter than the height of the screen. I'll create variables called contentOffsetY and maxContentOffsetY:  `CGFloat contentOffsetY = offsetY - contentInsetY - sectionInsetY; CGFloat maxContentOffsetY = self.collectionView.contentSize.height - self.collectionView.frame.size.height;` Then you can alter your contentOffsetY: `if (maxContentOffsetY < 0) {maxContentOffsetY = 0;} if (contentOffsetY > maxContentOffsetY) { contentOffsetY = maxContentOffsetY;}`

Answer (score 7):

Solution in Swift,

```
let section: Int = 0 // Top

if let cv = self.collectionView {

    cv.layoutIfNeeded()

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: section)
    if let attributes =  cv.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath) {

        let topOfHeader = CGPoint(x: 0, y: attributes.frame.origin.y - cv.contentInset.top)
        cv.setContentOffset(topOfHeader, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Props to Gene De Lisa: http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/scroll-to-uicollectionview-header/

Comment: This code works, but as the other solutions on this page suggested, you need to put a `cv.layoutIfNeeded()` function before you call `cv.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind` else this code will crash if the cv is not ready.

Answer (score 2):

```
// scroll to selected index
NSIndexPath* cellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:sectionIndex];
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attr = [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader atIndexPath:cellIndexPath];
UIEdgeInsets insets = self.collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets;

CGRect rect = attr.frame;
rect.size = self.collectionView.frame.size;
rect.size.height -= insets.top + insets.bottom;
CGFloat offset = (rect.origin.y + rect.size.height) - self.collectionView.contentSize.height;
if ( offset > 0.0 ) rect = CGRectOffset(rect, 0, -offset);

[self.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing the solutions don't manage is if you are pinning section headers. The methods work fine with unpinned headers, but if your headers are pinned, while scrolling to a section above the current section, it will stop once the section header appears (which will be for the bottom row of your section). That may be desirable in some cases but I think the goal is to put the top of the section at the top of the screen.

In which case you need to take the methods above and adjust them a bit. For instance:

```
UICollectionView *cv = self.collectionView;
CGFloat contentInsetY = cv.contentInset.top;
CGFloat offsetY = [cv layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:ip].frame.origin.y;
CGFloat sectionHeight =
[cv layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader atIndexPath:ip].frame.size.height;
[cv setContentOffset:CGPointMake(cv.contentOffset.x, offsetY - contentInsetY - sectionHeight) animated:YES];
```

Now you are basically scrolling the first row of your section to visible, less the height of its section header. This will put the section header on the top where you want it with pinned headers so the direction of the scroll won't matter anymore. I didn't test with section insets.