# How to convert from UICollectionElementKindSection.Header to NSString?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uicollectionview

I'm using Xamarin.iOS. How can I convert `UICollectionElementKindSection.Header` to `NSString`?

> Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert`UIKit.UICollectionElementKindSection' expression to type `Foundation.NSString' (CS1503)

I tried the following:

```
UICollectionElementKindSection.Header.ToString();
(NSString)UICollectionElementKindSection.Header;
(string)UICollectionElementKindSection.Header;
```

Everytime I get a build error.

Comment: Please show your current "conversion" code.

Comment: I added some examples.

Comment: How is this related to [tag:c#]?

Comment: @MickyDuncan because it's Xamarin.

Comment: @testing So did you resolve your problem? If yes, please provide an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

For type-safety `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` (and other values)  are mapped to an enum, `UICollectionElementKindSectionKey`. That makes code completion a lot easier (in the IDE) and remove potential typos/mistakes in code.

Turning the enum values into a `string` (and then an `NSString`) is possible - but that won't create the same `NSString` constant that ObjC applications used (even less since, sometime, Apple uses pointers, not string content, for constant comparison).

If you need to use an API that does not use the `enum` but needs that constant you can do:

```
IntPtr uikit = Dlfcn.dlopen (Constants.UIKitLibrary, 0);
NSString header = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant (uikit, "UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader");
```

Note: if that's an API part of Xamarin.iOS.dll then please let us [know](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com). We'll either expose the constant or provide an overload that accept the enum.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Basically, I was trying to replicate [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18364381/426227). Code: `CollectionView.GetLayoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement (UICollectionElementKindSection.Header, indexPath);`. Is this an API part?

Answer (score 0):

`(NSString)UICollectionElementKindSection.Header.ToString()` throws no build error anymore. My app still doesn't work but it's for another reason.